# How to get container to have height grow up, not down when content is added?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container that allows users to add more text to it through an `input`. The container is `position:absolute` with a `top` on it. When a user adds to the container through the `input` the height of the container grows, but downwards. Is there a way to get the bottom of the container to stay where it is, and have the height grow upwards.

In this fiddle example I will provide I have tried doing a `bottom` instead of a `top`, and that seems to work how I want. However, in my app I have calculations that are mounting the app to the page, and `bottom` is something I cant always count on, but `top` is something that I can count on and the app mounts correctly depending on screen width and edge detection calculations.

So is there a way to have it grow up with a `top`?

```js
$('form').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var inputVal = $('.input').val();
  var html = '<div class="content">'+inputVal+'</div>'
  $('.container').append(html)
});
```

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:300px;
  position:absolute;
  top:300px;
}
.content{
  padding:10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="type, hit enter">  
</form>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need calculate top position of container by subtracting changed height of it (https://jsfiddle.net/hqb4kmtm/13/):

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputVal = $('.input').val();
    var html = '<div class="content">'+inputVal+'</div>'
    var container = $('.container');
    var heightBefore = container.height();
    container.append(html);
    var heightAfter = container.height();
    container.css({top:container.offset().top + heightBefore - heightAfter});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
.container{
   border:1px solid #000;
   width:300px;
   position:absolute;
   height: auto;
   bottom:30px;
}
```

Check out a working example on [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hqb4kmtm/4/)

The downside of this approach (and what you want to do in general) is that when new text occupies the whole space above `container` div, it will mess up with your existing elements. To solve this, you have to track the height change on `container` div and update `bottom` property.

Comment: Yours is the better answer. +1

Comment: OP said `bottom` is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="target">
  </div>
  <div class="content">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputVal = $('.input').val();
  var html = '<div class="content">'+inputVal+'</div>'
  $('.target').append(html)
});
```

Is what you are looking for - hope that helps. Basically all you were doing was appending the input to the wrong div. This solution also maintains the exact same CSS styling that you requested...